# Unable to convert template arguments to match function arguments

Tags: c++, function, templates, function-parameter

I have 3 functions in a header file

```
template <typename T>
const T &minD(T const& a, T const& b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        return b;
    }
    else
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

> This is the objective function with which I am trying to match parameters to the arguments

```
char *minD(char * a, char * b)
{
    if (strcmp(a, b) > 0)
    {
        return b;
    }
    else
    {
        return a;
    }
}
```

> This is a function that has to call both functions written above based on the parameter types.

```
template <typename T>
const T &minD(T const &a, T const &b, T const &c)
{
    return minD(minD(a, b), c);
}
```

My goal is if the given arguments in the above function match the char* type, the minD with char* type arguments has to be called. If the argument type is any other type than it should call the 1st function which has template type arguments.

The first thing I did was tried calling the minD(minD(&a, &b), &c) and change the function2 to `const char *minD(const char * a, const char * b)`, but the compiler says cannot convert const T * to const char *.
The second thing I did was tried changing the parameter type of the 2nd function to 
`const char * minD(const char& a, const char& b)` and called function with `minD(minD(a, b), c)`, but then compiler throws an error about possible data loss from const T to const char conversion.

> One thing to note here is that I cannot change the parameter type of

```
template <typename T>
const T &minD(T const &a, T const &b, T const &c)
```

Sample function calls:

```
val = minD(42, 7, 68);
```

This call is a function call to the 3rd function and then the 3rd function has to call 1st function in order to get the right answer.

```
const char *  const s0 = "CSC";
const char *  const s1 = "461";
const char *  const s2 = "Optimized C++";
s = minD(s0, s1, s2);
```

This call is a function call to the 3rd function and then the 3rd function has to call 2nd function in order to get the right answer.

I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Why are you not using `const char *` in `minD`?

Comment: Oh I am. That was my first try as I explained above. It throws an error that cannot convert const T * to const char *.

Comment: I mean `const char *minD(const char * a, const char * b)`.

Comment: A `const T` can't be implicitly converted to `T`. In your case, `const char*` can't be converted to `char*`.

Comment: @cigien . It works because it always matches the arguments to 1st function. The moment you comment that out. It will throw errors right away.

Comment: Also, having `char*` as arguments to your function overload makes no sense, since it means you can't use it with literal strings.

Comment: @cigien The name has templates because my program is trying to convert T type arguments to match T and char * type simultaneously.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do not care about any other types of arguments, All I care about is the two sample function calls have to call appropriate functions.

Comment: I added some more comments for clarification as to what I am expecting.

Comment: The problem is that in the function `template <typename T> const T &minD(T const &a, T const &b, T const &c)` you *can't* call `char *minD(char * a, char * b)`, because the arguments in the template function is of type `const char*` which can't be converted to `char*`. You need to change the string overload of `minD` to take `const char*` arguments.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I already updated the question where I explain this situation in the paragraph that starts with "The first thing I did..."

Comment: Please reproduce your compiler error messages verbatim. Anyway, you cannot both return a reference and not return a reference from the same function. Not without making an explicit effort to do so.

Comment: Well then that's another problem because if the argument `c` is a `const char*`, then `&c` will be a `const char**`. You shouldn't be using the address-of operator when passing the arguments to `minD`. Perhaps you misunderstand the use of `&` in different contexts?

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against the wall for a long time I was able to come up with a solution.

> It turns out that there is probably no way to modify these 3 given functions to match both scenarios.

So, my solution was to add an overloaded method of minD:

```
template <typename T>
const T* minD(const T* a, const T* b, const T* c)
{
    return minD(minD(a, b), c);
}
```

Also, I changed the signature of minD with two char * parameters like this:

```
const char *minD(const char * a, const char * b)
```

Now, on this call

```
val = minD(42, 7, 68);
```

It matches the minD function with 3 const T& parameters and from inside it calls minD with 2 const T& parameters.
However, on this call

```
const char *  const s0 = "CSC";
const char *  const s1 = "461";
const char *  const s2 = "Optimized C++";
s = minD(s0, s1, s2);
```

It matches the newly added minD function with 3 char* parameters, which in turns calls the updated minD function with 2 char* parameters.

Hence, it solves this problem.